# ncurses subversion repository browser

Tags: command-line, subversion

Does anyone have a smooth repository browser they can use on the command line? I'm finding the `svn ls` command to be a bit tedious. I've considered using a CLI browswer such as [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) to brows the html of my repository. I'd like to find alternatives less tortuous, that's all.

Comment: For what it's worth, I often use `elinks` as an SVN repository browser, but if you want something a little more lightweight, you can try something like `w3m`.  Also, keep in mind that you can usually do things like `svn ls ^/trunk/path/to/directory` as long as your PWD is within a working copy.

Comment: I wrote an interface from my directory editor to svn for the 1.6 series which let me sort by revision number, last checkin author, etc.  A web browser doesn't address the issue of managing the working files.

Comment: Good catch Thomas. I was hoping that someone has nabbed the sweet functionality of tortuous' features (easy file browsing and 1-click logs/commits) and put it into a package comparable to midnight commander. How sweet would that be?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I've used elinks to browse my repository before, but I've had trouble saving my credentials. Every time I check it out, I need log back in. That's annoying. Plus, you don't get the external properties, logs, revision #'s etc.